# Send/receive friend request using XMPP server in Android

Tags: android, xmpp, chat

I am creating a application based on XMPP chat Messenger. Now we have some customize feature needs to be implement in the app like Send/Receive friend request within the messenger. How we can do that?

```
roster = _connection.getRoster();
roster.createEntry(userID, nickname, null);
```

Currently we are using this method but it directly added the contact in my messenger contact list. Now what I want is to ask if any new friend request comes like BBM (Blackberry Messenger). then it should ask for confirmation before adding directly to contact lists it is happening currently.

Comment: is your problem solved?? I have the same problem yr. Can u please help me if you are done with

Comment: can u recive any frend requrest?

Answer (score 0):

I can help you out. I have fully functional messaging app. I assume you are using Smack or Asmack as the XMPP library.

Adding a friend

```
Presence request = new Presence(Presence.Type.subscribe);
        packet.setTo("john@ejabberd.org");
        mXMPPConnection.sendPacket(packet);
```

Accepting a request

```
Presence accept = new Presence(Presence.Type.subscribed);
                    accept.setTo("john@ejabberd.org");
                    mXMPPConnection.sendPacket(accept);
```

Ask me if you need anything else :) Cheers

Comment: How to get list for friend request and send invitation for friend ?@Kishath

Answer (score 0):

Send Friend Request/Invitation [user1@domain],

```
Presence presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.subscribe);
presence.setTo("user2@domain");
connection.sendStanza(presence);
```

Accept Friend Request/Invitation [user2@domain],

```
Presence presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.subscribed);
presence.setTo("user1@domain.com");
connection.sendStanza(presence);
```

Every time user2 will login, server will send the subscribe presence packets to user2 until user2 send any response against the request.

Comment: I am not getting everytime in user2. which listener should I use?